# fluentd in_http plugin give wrong time

Tags: fluentd

this is my config:

```
<source>
  @type http
  port 8080
  bind 0.0.0.0
  body_size_limit 1m
  keepalive_timeout 20s
  cors_allow_origins ["http://example.net"]
  add_remote_addr true
</source>

<match log>
  @type sql
  host 127.0.0.1
  port 3306
  database user
  adapter mysql2
  username user
  password pass
  socket /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  flush_interval 1s
  num_threads 2
  <table>
    table http_logs
    column_mapping 'timestamp:created_at,REMOTE_ADDR:ip,name:name,value:value,value2:value2,url:url'
  </table>
</match>
```

I am sending the data into mysql, 
mysql and fluentd server are using the same time and timezone, but fluentd always send the time 3 hours backwards so if the real time is

> ```
> root@fluentd:~# date
> Mon Aug  7 21:22:04 IDT 2017
> ```

fluentd is inserting new data with time of:

> Mon Aug  7 18:22:04 IDT 2017

I looked in fluentd input and output plugins and there no config for timezone

Answer (score 0):

I think that what happen is that fluentd converts your timestamp to [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) format (with no time zone) after that mysql is converting UTC time format to GMT+0 which is probably -3 hours from your timezone.

you can configure fluentd timezone like in this [example](https://www.fluentd.org/blog/fluentd-v0.10.56-is-released):

```
<match pattern>
  type file
  path /var/log/fluent/myapp
  time_slice_format %Y%m%d
  time_slice_wait 10m
  time_format %Y%m%dT%H%M%S%z
  timezone +08:00
</match>
```

Comment: I am getting [warn]: parameter 'timezone' in <match log>. I am guess that   @type sql just don't support this